# Fortnite PS4 controller button issues

Tags: ps4, controllers, fortnite-battle-royale

My controller for PS4 is playing up when I play fortnite.  If I press the stick down I look up, when I press up I look down in Fortnite. Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is probably a setting to invert the Y-axis in the options menu. I do not have Fortnite, so I cannot check it, but many other games do have it. Toggle this setting, and it should be normal again.

Answer (score 1):

It is on inverted axis. You can change this in the "controls" settings. Once done, it should be fine. I had to fix this when I played, too.

Answer (score -1):

You can rest your controller. You can go to the settings and reset your controls to default. Or y-axis reset the controller.